# mysql nested query with 4 queries

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I have an issue with mysql queries,
in fact, I have to build a web page with charts, and I need to fetch the data from the database as follow:

1- Get the total of data received per month, per centre ( it mean country ) for the current year,

2- Get the total of data wich has NOT been done per month, per centre for the current year,

3- Get the total of data which has not been done AND the date exceed 20 days , per month, per centre for the current year.

So, all in all, I'm able to fetch the data for all thoses queries, no problem about that.
The issue I am facing is, I need those queries embedded into 1 single query returning me a table like that:

```
| monthname | total | totalNotDone | totalExceed20Days |
|  January  | 52    |    3         |      1            |
|  February | 48    |    4         |      0            |
|  March    | 54    |    1         |      3            |
```

etc.

Here is a sqlfiddle showing the issue :

edited : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cc9c/1

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys, I'm really stuck.

Comment: There's quite a lot of irrelevant info in that fiddle, isn't there? Get rid of it then get back to us.

Comment: Please post the relevant information here. Show the schema for the table(s), some sample input data, and the query you tried.

Comment: It is best, as @Barmar pointed out, to put the relevant information in the question.

Comment: here is a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cc9c/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic queries are fine. What you need to do is treat each of them as a virtual table, and `LEFT JOIN` them together.  Then your toplevel `SELECT` can choose the appropriate values for your overall table.

```
SELECT afftotal.date,
       afftotal.centre_id,
       afftotal.total AS total,
       af20.total AS total_20,
       afempty.total AS total_empty
FROM (
    /* select total of affaires per month and per centre for this year */
select month(aff_date) AS `date`,
       centre_id,
       count(*) AS `total` 
    from affaires
    where year(aff_date) = 2014 
    group by month(aff_date), centre_id
 ) AS afftotal
LEFT JOIN (
  /* select total of affaires per month and per centre for this year where the affaire has been done
     before 20 days.  */
select month(`affaires`.`aff_date`) AS `date`,
       centre_id,
       count(*) AS `total` 
    from `affaires`
    where year(`affaires`.`aff_date`) = 2014 
    and DATEDIFF(`affaires`.`aff_date`, `affaires`.`date_creation_pdl`) > 20
    group by monthname(`affaires`.`aff_date`), centre_id
 ) AS af20   ON afftotal.date = af20.date
            AND afftotal.centre_id = af20.centre_id
LEFT JOIN (

   /* select total of affaires where the date_creation_pdl is empty */

select month(affaires.aff_date) as `date`, 
       centre_id,
       count(*) as total
from affaires
where date_creation_pdl is null
and year(affaires.aff_date) = 2014
group by monthname(affaires.aff_date)
 ) AS afempty   ON afftotal.date = afempty.date 
               AND afftotal.centre_id = afempty.centre_id

ORDER BY afftotal.centre_id, afftotal.date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d563e/24/0

Notice that this is summarizing both by centre_id and date, so you can get all the centre_id values in a single query.

Notice also that the `ORDER BY` clause is placed at the end of the whole query.

What you have are three subqueries, three virtual tables if you will, each with three columns: a date, a centre_id, and a total. You `LEFT JOIN` them together `ON` two of those columns.

I had to muck around with your queries a bit to make them have similar column names and column data formats, so the `LEFT JOIN` operations have a regular structure.

Comment: very cleaver, didnt know that type of nesting, very nice trick :)